# Magento 2 - Require Js not a function error

Tags: magento2, requirejs, requirejs-config.js

Firstly, yes I'm in developer mode - and yes i've got the caché turned off and flushing it ( i've also deleted pub/static a fair few times ).

**My issue:**

I have an extension which adds a page to the admin area of the site on this page Im using **require js** to call in plugins to do things. Here is my requirejs file:

```
var config = {
  map: {
    '*': {
        nestable:  'Vender_Default/js/jquery.nestable.min'
    }
  }
};
```

Which is inside of the following file:

> vender/default/view/adminhtml/web/requirejs-config.js

and then in the page I'm doing the following:

```
require([
        'jquery',
        'nestable'
    ], function($, nestable) {
        $('#nestable').nestable({
                    group: 1,
                    maxDepth: 15
                }).on('change', updateOutput);
        });
```

Which i thought was correct, however i get the following errors:

> Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined at jquery.nestable.min.js:1

and

> TypeError: $(...).nestable is not a function

Which clearly its not now, because of the first error. Does anyone have any idea why I am getting this issue? I can't seem to get my head around why its not working. And most other questions on here don't seem to be the same issue.

** Have changed jQuery to $ and still receiving the error.

Thanks

Comment: You need to check your third party JS. If it is not compatible with require js then you will face error.  Please check below link for reference http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/custom_js.html

Comment: try deploying adding -f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, Thanks for @Rakesh-jesadiya for the answer, as i was doing that part wrong!! And have changed it.

But i've found out that doing the following to the nestable.min.js file fixes it:

```
define([
    'jquery'
], function($){
    // do nestable jquery plugin here.
});
```

Looks like the plugin doesn't know what jQuery is, and defining the jquery around the plugin worked.

Can anyone explain this?

I assumed requiring jquery before the plugin, in the file would do this? Its only taken me... 30+ minutes to find the answer >_<

Answer (score 1):

You need to do as below, need to change jQuery to $ as argument,

```
require([
    'jquery',
    'nestable'
], function($, nestable) {
        $('#nestable').nestable({
            group: 1,
            maxDepth: 15
        }).on('change', updateOutput);
});
```

Comment: Yes, i tried this as i'd seen it in other places. However Im still getting the error - even after the change.

Comment: did you try to run upgrade and deploy command

Comment: Shouldn't need to deploy as currently in dev mode. However i will run the upgrade command to see.